# Why does path analysis require variables to be measured on an interval scale?

Tags: path-model

According to [this document](http://computerwranglers.com/Com531/Handouts/path.pdf):

"In order to “correctly” use path analysis, Kerlinger and Fedhazur (1973) incidate that the following four assumptions must be met: (a) relations among variables are linear, additive, and causal (curvilinear and multiplicative relationships and inter— actions are excluded); (b) residuals (to be introduced later) are not correlated; (c) a one-way causal flow exists; and (d) variables are measured on an interval scale."

What is the reason for this requirement of interval scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document is incorrect. At least the exogenous variables can be nominal or ordinal, see for example:

Heise, David R. (1972). Employing nominal variables, induced variables, and block variables in path analysis. *Sociological Methods & Research*, 1(2): 147--173.